# Finding exact roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I know of the rational root theorem to find all rational zeros and Newtons method of approximating zeros, but what if all the solutions are irrational/imaginary and you need exact answers for the irrational roots.

For example:  $3{x}^{3}-6{x}^{2}-7=0$

Comment: look at this [paper](http://www.ias.ac.in/resonance/Volumes/15/04/0347-0350.pdf) that gives formulas to compute all the roots of a cubic equation

Comment: For cubics, there is the Cardano method, and more. For details [please see this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function)  Quartics can also be handled generally. For higher degree, only special kinds of equations can be handled algebraically.